# Restructuring Elasticsearch model for fast aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

My business domain is real estate listings, and i'm trying to build a faceted UI. So i need to do aggregations to know how many listings have 1 beds, 2 beds, how many in this price range, how many with a pool etc etc. Pretty standard stuff.

Currently my model is like this:

```
{
   "beds": 1,
   "baths": 1,
   "price": 100000,
   "features": ['pool','aircon'],
   "inspections": [{
      "startsOn": "2019-01-20"
   }]
}
```

To build my faceted UI, i'm doing multiple aggregations, e.g:

```
{
   "aggs" : {
        "beds" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "beds" }
        },
        "baths" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "baths" }
        },
        "features" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "features" }
        }
    }
}
```

You get the idea. If i've got 10 fields, i'm doing 10 aggregations.

But after seeing [this article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/modeling-data-for-fast-aggregations), i'm thinking i should just re-structure my model to be like this:

```
{
   "beds": 1,
   "baths": 1,
   "price": 100000,
   "features": ['pool','aircon'],
   "attributes": ['bed_1','bath_1','price_100000-200000','has_pool','has_aircon','has_inspection_tomorrow']
}
```

Then i only need the 1 agg:

```
{
   "aggs": {
      "attributes": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "attributes"
         }
       }
   }
}
```

So i've got a couple of questions.

1. Is the *only* drawback in this approach that logic is moved to the client? If so, im happy with this - for performance, since i don't see this logic changing very often.
2. Can i leverage this field in my *queries* too? For example, what if i wanted to match all documents with 1 bedroom *and* price = 100000 *and* with a pool, etc. Terms queries work on an 'any' match, but how can i find documents where the array of values contain *all* the provided terms?

Alternatively, if you can think of a better structure for modelling for search speed, please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen performance issues so far?

Comment: @Val I haven't even built it yet :) just trying to gauge feedback or edge cases which might cause issues

Comment: Then, I have only one thing to say: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), i.e. you can only improve what exists, so build it first, then improve it, not the other way around ;-)

Comment: I've built a system using my original document. Performs ok, but I'm wondering if I should try this approach as I hypothesise it'll perform better. So, I'm _trying_ to improve it. I'll be testing my theory, but was seeking advice too in case there are drawbacks I'm not aware of.

Comment: One drawback is that if you ever decide to change the ranges (price or otherwise), you'll have to reindex all your data. Perhaps also, someone might want to see a 100K house appear in the 50K-100K range and not 100K-200K range. The only way to know if it's going to get better to create a clone of your system, implement that alternative and compare... that's the only way to know...

Comment: @Val regarding the price range, it needs to appear in both. But I can do that right? For values on the bounding value, they'll have two price attribute values

Comment: Of course, feel free to try it out and see whether it's better or not, no one can tell. I'm just not sure at all that this will bring you anything.

Answer (score 1):

For the second point your can use the `terms set query` ([doc here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html)).

This query is like a terms query, but you will have control over how many terms must match.

You can configure it through a script like that :

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "terms_set": {
            "codes" : {
                "terms" : ["bed_1","bath_1","price_100000-200000"],
                "minimum_should_match_script": {
                   "source": "params.num_terms"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

will require all params to match

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Aren't scripts meant to be avoided unless absolutely necessary though?

Comment: All script dont have the same cpu cost/overhead. Only experimentation on a populated cluster will tell you if the approach is working for your needs. And since this script doesnt access document values it should be light

Comment: Cool. Kind of a side question, how can i experiment on a populated cluster? Rally seems best for benchmarking the cluster itself  (e.g index/node settings). I want to benchmark different queries. Do i need to just write my own jmeter scripts, or is there something better?

Comment: is there a way to evaluate your production data volume? ( numbers of documents etc ? ) Then I think to best way is to gather a sample of real estate documents and create an application able to push randomized data (from your real data) to your index. It should not be too complicated

Comment: yep, i've done that. I'm asking once you've got the data, how to benchmark it? E.g how to generate load and measure performance? Is there something ES specific, or just use jmeter from the _outside_ and capture e2e response latency?

Comment: es rally is here to avoid spending hours with Jmeter. You could create your own track specific to your needs see https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adding_tracks.html and https://esrally.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adding_tracks.html